# how to use docker image tag parsing regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I copied this regex for parsing docker image tag in Python.

```
^(?P<repository>[\w.\-_]+((?::\d+|)(?=/[a-z0-9._-]+/[a-z0-9._-]+))|)(?:/|)(?P<image>[a-z0-9.\-_]+(?:/[a-z0-9.\-_]+|))(:(?P<tag>[\w.\-_]{1,127})|)$
```

Can someone rewrite this regex in Javascript?

Test string:

```
alpine

alpine:latest

_/alpine

_/alpine:latest

alpine:3.7

docker.example.com/gmr/alpine:3.7

docker.example.com:5000/gmr/alpine:latest

pse/anabroker:latest
```

The Javascript version [here](https://regex101.com/r/a98UqN/1) has a pattern error without any matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your named groups have a different syntax in JS and the / needs escaping

https://regex101.com/r/EpwtjK/1

```
^(?<repository>[\w.\-_]+((?::\d+|)(?=\/[a-z0-9._-]+\/[a-z0-9._-]+))|)(?:\/|)(?<image>[a-z0-9.\-_]+(?:\/[a-z0-9.\-_]+|))(:(?<tag>[\w.\-_]{1,127})|)$
```

Comment: It works fine in javascript. you are a lifesaver bro :)